# customize subform Query

Tags: ms-access, vba, subform

so what i am doing is i created a form with the handle

```
Dim oSub
Dim oQuery As QueryDef

Set oSub = CreateControl(oForm.Name, acSubform, acDetail, "", "", xPos, currentY + 1000, breite, oHeight)
oSub.Name = "sub000"                        

strSQL = "select * from testTable"

queryname = "abfSAM000"
Set oQuery = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(queryname, strSQL)
CurrentDb.QueryDefs(queryname).sql = strSQL

oSub.SourceObject = "Query." & queryname

Forms!Form1!sub000.Form.NavigationButtons = False
```

The Problem now is that i want to set the NavigationButtons of the Subform to false.
Doing so i always get the error

"The Expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesnt exist"

So if i check in Debug Mode if the Form exists (fe. i type ?oSub.name in direct window) it shows "sub000" and also in the designview i see the subform with the name "sub000"- so obviously the subform exists- so its closed? But what

Any ideas on that??

Thanks all!

EDIT: I found the Solution. I had to switch th oForm to FormView first and then turn of the buttons... i guess this is th emoment when the form object gets instantiated and appears as real object to access. Just a guess though

Comment: please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Forms!mainform!subform.Form.NavigationButtons = false

Comment: @geeFlo i still get the same error : Run-time error 2467- the expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesnt exist... 
any idea? i will update the Question description soon

Comment: you have to substitute mainform, subform with the name of your forms.